# Adding language option to the existing defaults fullcalendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

Am trying to change the default language options provided by the fullcalendar in show.html.erb as below:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({lang: 'es'});
```

But the new language is not reflected in the calendar.I have used the some  options like destroy,render,refresh etc., in order to refresh the calendar with the new language.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Where are you putting this javascript code? If you want it on page load, it would need to be wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() {});`. Is the calendar loading at all?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that lang-all.js is included (or just the es one)

So either load this script at some point:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.6/lang-all.js

Or do something like this in rails:

`//= require fullcallendar/lang-all`

I'm not familiar with ruby-on-rails but [this issue](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails/issues/24) seems to say that.